# PHP Game won't recognize input from form, doesn't run switch-case statement

Tags: php, forms, input, switch-statement

I have a text-based exploring game based off of [HackingWithPHP](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/21/4/2/text-game-v1) that I'm working on, and my code just won't take input from the form I have for commands. It probably does take input, it's just that the PHP I have doesn't recognize it. Another problem is that the `switch ($command) {` statement that I have doesn't seem to run. It just skips over the entire thing. I can't figure out what's going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Code:
index.php (I have this as a .php file so the $input variable can be passed from this file to game.php)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Urban Adventure</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <?php
                include_once 'game.php';
            ?>
            <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "">
                <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="" name="input" style="width: 600; position: absolute; bottom: 0; z-index: 2;">
            </FORM>
        </div>
        <?php
            $input = $_POST["input"];
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

game.php:

```
<?php
    include_once 'index.php';
    print($input);
    $World = simplexml_load_file("gameworld.xml");
    $CurrentPos = 0;
    $Done = 0;
    print "<br>";
    printplace();
    function printplace() {
    GLOBAL $World, $CurrentPos;
    $Room = $World->ROOM[$CurrentPos];
    $Name = $Room->NAME;
    $Desc = wordwrap((string)$Room->DESC);
    print "$Name<br>";
    print str_repeat('-', strlen($Name));
    print "<br>$Desc<br>";
    if ((string)$Room->NORTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->NORTH;
        print "North: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$Room->SOUTH != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->SOUTH;
        print "South: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->WEST;
        print "West: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
        $index = (int)$Room->EAST;
        print "East: {$World->ROOM[$index]->NAME}<br>";
    }
    print "<br>";
}

$input = explode(' ', $input);
print "<br>";
foreach ($input as $command) {
    switch ($command) {
        case 'north':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->NORTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go north!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'south':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->SOUTH;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go south!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'west':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->WEST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go west!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'east':
            if ((string)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST != '-') {
                $CurrentPos = (int)$World->ROOM[$CurrentPos]->EAST;
                printplace() ;
            } else {
                print "You cannot go east!<br>";
            }
            break;
        case 'look':
            printplace() ;
            break;
        default:
            print "not a valid command... <br>";
            break;
    }
}
print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";
?>
```

What happens is that the input doesn't work, the switch-case statement doesn't work, and the `print "<br>Thanks for playing!<br>";` runs before the switch-case statement. Sorry if I can't describe this correctly. You might want to check out the real thing here: [urbanadventure.dumpong.tk](http://urbanadventure.dumpong.tk) . You'll be able to see the real bugs going on there.

Comment: you don't assign the $input variable until after all of game.php is included

Comment: can you clarify? I don't quite understand, sorry. Are you saying that I shouldn't assign $input until all of game.php is included? If so, how can I do that (haven't I already included it? sorry I'm a noob), or are you saying that my problem is that you don't assign the $input variable until all of game.php is included?

Comment: move `<?php $input = $_POST["input"]; ?>` above the include - although there are other issues here

Comment: Input worked like a charm. Thank you! +1

Comment: @dagon please move your comment to the answer to the answer section so we can tag the question as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

move

```
<?php $input = $_POST["input"]; ?>
```

above the include - although there are other issues here